# Calculate Monthly Goal to reach target

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need a formula to calculate the goal of each month automatically. For example , if January is $10,000, I need Feb to automatically calculate target and adjust to the goal.

For example goal is $120,000

I tried using Goal seek. I have a goal to reach $120,000 in collections. If I collect 10,000 in January, I need my formula to adjust for Feb-Dec showing how much I need to collect to reach goal of $120,000. If I make another $10,000 in February, That means I have $100,000 left to reach, the goal from March to December should adjust accordingly. I would be adding each month actual amounts.

I have 3 rows - Months, Total Actual Collections $- Next MONTH TARGET

Comment: What are you asking? It is not clear. Also, what have you tried, what research have you done toward solving the problem yourself, and what were the results of your attempts?

Comment: I tried using Goal seek. I have a goal to reach $120,000 in collections. If I collect 10,000 in January, I need my formula to adjust for Feb-Dec showing how much I need to collect to reach goal of $120,000. If I make another $10,000 in February, That means I have $100,000 left to reach, the goal from March to December should adjust accordingly.

Comment: How is the data stored?

Comment: It's in Excel. Goal = 120,000 ..I would be adding each month actuals. I have 3 rows - Months, 
Total Actual Collections  $-    
Next MONTH TARGET

Comment: You want Excel to distribute the remaining goal across the months that do not have an actual amount entered? Or are you entering target values for each month?

Comment: I will only enter the actual. I want excel to distribute the goal across months for remaining months

Answer (score 2):

For the purpose of this answer, I have laid out the sheet with the goal in row `1`, the Months are in row `2`, actual in row `3` and target in row `4`. It looks like this;

[image]

First you want to enter a formula so the goal will count down as you enter actual amounts. To do this, enter the formula in `B2` that has the `goal-total in row 3`. This will subtract amounts received from the goal.

```
=120000-SUM(B3:M3)
```

Now enter a formula in row 4 to calculate your monthly target. Using an `IF` function, we can tell the formula to ignore the "actual" cell if it has a value in it. If it is blank, the calculation will run to divide the remaining goal amount in `B1` by the number of blank months in `B3:M3` to give you the monthly target. This formula can be copied to each cell in `B4:M4`.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B3), SUM($B$1/COUNTBLANK($B$3:$M$3)), "")
```

It will result in the sheet working like this;

[image]

***Closing note;*** if the sheet doesn't calculate automatically, you will need to press <kbd>F9</kbd> or set the sheet to automatic.

Answer (score 0):

Write your Months in a Row (A1 till M1), Write the Actual under it for the months you have, in the third Row start under January with the Goal/12 (B3=120000/12).
After writing the January Actual write in the Target under February (in C3) the following formula:

`=(120000-SUM($B$2:B2))/(12-COUNT($B$2:B2))`

and drag it in the same row till M3
Whenever you write a new actual it will calculate under the next months the new target

[image]

Comment: But this doesn't account for the surplus collected each month or if any month they collect less ?

Comment: It does and the picture proves it