# Monthly target vs actual with percentages

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2013

[Excel Project Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85xj1.png)

[image]

Hi guys

I need help with a formula to dynamically re-calculate my target based on the actual input.

1. On the screenshot from c4:n4 the user enters the percentage that must add up to 100%.
2. H8 user enters the yearly target to reach
3. C4:N14 enters the target based the percentages user provides and from c13:n13 user enters the actual amount for the month.

I need a dynamic formula that will re calculate everytime the user enters the actual amount for the month. I have visited this page [Calculate Monthly Goal to reach target](https://superuser.com/questions/1176687/calculate-monthly-goal-to-reach-target) and it does exactly what I want but I want it to be dynamic based on the percentage inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you're asking for, but if I've got it wrong, please comment below.

The monthly targets can be calculated with this formula, filled right from C14:

`=IFERROR($I8*C4-C13,"-")`

The amount Left is calculated with this formula in I10:

`=SUM(C14:N14)`

and the sums on the right are calculated with this formula in O4, O13, and O14:

`=SUM(C4:N4)`

These formulas give this result as the Actual monthly values are entered:

[image]

Comment: Hi Bandersnatch, thank you for taking your time...at the moment the product already do that, now I need it to be dynamic for example on C13 you have entered 8000, now I need a formula that will recalculate the target based on what is left... e.g. we have 100000 as our goal and the user entered their percentages. if for April I enter 8000 meaning I will be left with 92000. I need it to recalculate the target based on the remaining target

Comment: Sorry for the delay on this.  I have edited the answer to address your comments.